# Selecting knockout.js custom content in observableArray within foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following snippet of html:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: ptData">
            <tr id="Tr1">
                <td><a data-bind="attr: {href: '/ProjectTrack/IssueGrid.aspx?IssueID='+ptId}">PT Launch</a></td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" data-bind="text: ptId">
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" data-bind="text: ptProject">
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" data-bind="text: ptTitle">
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" data-bind="text: ptPriority">
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" data-bind="text: ptType">
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" data-bind="text: ptStatus">
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" data-bind="text: ptUpdated">
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" data-bind="text: ptAssignedTo">
                </td>
                <td style="display: none" data-bind="text: ptUrl">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I have the following viewModel with dynamic content pushed to it:

```
var viewModel = {
        ptData: ko.observableArray([])
    };



function DataResult(ptId, ptProject, ptTitle, ptPriority, ptType, ptStatus, ptUpdated, ptAssignedTo, ptDesc, ptUrl) {
        this.ptId = ko.observable(ptId);
        this.ptProject = ko.observable(ptProject);
        this.ptTitle = ko.observable(ptTitle);
        this.ptPriority = ko.observable(ptPriority);
        this.ptType = ko.observable(ptType);
        this.ptStatus = ko.observable(ptStatus);
        this.ptUpdated = ko.observable(ptUpdated);
        this.ptAssignedTo = ko.observable(ptAssignedTo);
        this.ptDesc = ko.observable(ptDesc);
        this.ptUrl = ko.observable(ptUrl);
    }
```

I have a jQuery ajax call to return data that is populated in a DataResult object, and each DataResult object is pushed to the viewModel.ptData.  The following knockout.js command doesn't seem to work in the HTML snippet:

```
"attr: {href: '/ProjectTrack/IssueGrid.aspx?IssueID='+ptId".
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems good could you post this in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind to an expression (here you are building the link with `+`) where you have observable properties (`ptId`) you must invoke them like as functions. So you are missing the `()`

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: '/ProjectTrack/IssueGrid.aspx?IssueID=' + ptId() }">
```

However if you would create a computed obseravable to generate the link:

```
function DataResult(ptId, ....) {        
        this.ptId = ko.observable(ptId);
        this.launchLink = ko.computed(function(){
            return '/ProjectTrack/IssueGrid.aspx?IssueID=' + this.ptId()
        }, this);
}
```

Then you don't need the `()` in your binding, because now you directly bind to an observable:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: launchLink }">
```

Comment: Yup that did it.  I did not fully understand how to bind properly.  Thanks for the assist.